# how to run add-in on different system?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2005, add-in

I have one shared add-in created in visual Studio 2005. This Add-in is worked on my system fine but if i tried to run this add-in on different system then it is not working. I found the problem behinde this but is it correct or not.
In my view the problem is when we create add-in through visual studio then the entry of this add-in is internally done by visual studio in registray file, so if we can try to run add-in created on particular system,to different system then this is not working because of this.
my process to run this add-in on different system is
copy my add-in project to different system and then build this project and tried to run add-in but its not working.
so is there any solution for this??

Answer (score 0):

Create a *Setup and Deployment* type project for your add-in. The resulting installer will create the Registry entries needed to run your add-in.

The required Registry entries for Office add-ins are described here:

> **[Registry Entries for Application-Level Add-Ins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386106.aspx)**